# Termux_Change_Repo using another way with command line

Tags: android, termux

I want to change reop mirror in Termux with cmd typing.

Is there a way that I can do this without showing the blue screen and do it only by a command line??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

yes you can by adding mirror link to source.list

```
echo "YOUR URL" > $PREFIX/etc/apt/sources.list
```

check this to know more [link](http://th3cr00k3dm4n.unaux.com/blog/how-to-change-termux-mirror/)